# MognoDB: JSON util is deprecated

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

Up to now, I've been using this code in order to create a `DBObject` from a json string:

```
DBObject metadataObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

However, `com.mongodb.util.JSON` is deprecated, and it's recomended to use `BasicDBObject.parse` instead.

```
DBObject metadataObject = (DBObject)BasicDBObject.parse(jsonString);
```

Nevertheless, when `jsonString` is an array (like `"[{k: 'v'},{o: 'p'}]"` it throws an exception. `JSON.parse` works fine.

o, What I want to get is using `BasicDBObject.parse(...)`:

```
(DBObject)JSON.parse("[{'hola': 'adeu'}, {'departament': [{'ambit': 'just', 'name': 'ts'}]}]");
```

code would be (this code crashes):

```
(DBObject)BasicDBObject.parse("[{'hola': 'adeu'}, {'departament': [{'ambit': 'just', 'name': 'ts'}]}]");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this,because there is no BasicDBList::parse method

```
BsonArray parse = BsonArray.parse(json);
BasicDBList dbList = new BasicDBList();
dbList.addAll(parse);
DBObject dbObject = dbList;
```

BasicDBObject.parse(...) is actually for parsing objects, not arrays which are represened by BasicDBList class.

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid JSON:

```
[{k: 'v'},{o: 'p'}]
```

1. There should be quotes around the attribute names.
2. Quotes should be double quotes (`"`) not single quotes (`'`).

This example is not valid either:

```
[{'hola': 'adeu'}, {'departament': [{'ambit': 'just', 'name': 'ts'}]}]
```

References:

- [The JSON grammar](https://json.org)
- [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

Comment: I assume the reason for this confusion is that the Mongo query language looks like JSON, however it accepts invalid JSON such as your first example.

Comment: That is a fair assumption.